# defining values in dictionary based on other values there

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the best way to achieve something like this:

```
dic = {
    'foo': Tree(),
    'foobar': #the method 'branch()' executed on 'foo'
}
```

Can this be done the way I described it, or should I use a second assignment with `dic['foobar'] = dic['foo'].branch()`?

Comment: What if there are 3 pairs in the dictionary? Remember dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: @Wooble I've edited my question to make it my intentions more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason why not do it like:

```
t = Tree()
dic = {'foo': t, 'foobar': t.branch()}
```

But maybe this trick can help you:

```
dic = {'foo': Tree(), 'foobar': lambda: dic['foo'].branch()}
```

The downside is, that you have to use `dic['foobar']()` instead of `dic['foobar']` and that the `.branch()` function is executed every time, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious answer is the best one. Thank you.